# Open .py file in Tkinter and supply user input through GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have written a piece of code which has a user input as follows:

```
var1 = input("Enter input here: ")
```

which are saved in the code to prompt some actions. I would like to call on this piece of code using a separate piece of Tkinter code.

The problem is my Tkinter code does call on the other input code, but the input value is already filled in as 'None'.  How can I get my Tkinter code to allow me to enter a use input when calling a separate piece of code?

Below is the Tkinter code:

```
my Tkinter code is below:

import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import *

root = Tk()

def import_print():
        proc = Popen('python testinput.py', stdout=PIPE, shell=TRUE)
        proc = proc.communicate()
        textbox.insert(END, proc)

def enter_stuff():
    print(E1.get())

textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()


B=Button(root,text="Press to Start",command=import_print)
B.pack()

B2=Button(root,text="Enter",command=enter_stuff)
B2.pack()

E1 = Entry(root)
E1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

The 'original' code that I am calling into Tkinter:

```
var1 = input("Enter User Input: ")

var1 = var1 * 5

print (var1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `input` and `tkinter` are two *different* mechanisms to make interactive programs.

*They do not mix.*

The `input` function requires that Python is running from a shell, while `tkinter` programs create their own window.

Furthermore, Python scripts running in a terminal generally have a linear control flow. GUI programs like `tkinter` run in a continuous event processing loop.

Simply put, you should write your program to use *either* `tkinter` or `input`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  I thought I had read that, but the context was presented differently.  I am new to python so I really appreciate your feedback.